# Getting a web server certificate in ruby

Tags: ruby, ssl, certificate

I'm trying to write some ruby code to grab the Common Name (CN) value from a web server's SSL certificate but there doesn't seem to be any simple way to do this in ruby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I would beg to differ. It's documented well enough but not too many examples are available, which makes it a bit, but not too complicated :)

```
require 'openssl'

raw_cert = File.read (path_to_your_cert) # if your cert is in PEM or DER format
```

OR

```
raw_cert = OpenSSL::PKCS12.new(File.read(path_to_your_cert), your_pwd) # If you want to read a .p12 cert

cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(raw_cert)
cert.subject
=> **************/CN=<Your Common Name>/***************
```

So you can parse cert.subject to find out the common name you need.

You can read more in-depth on SSL certs at http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/X509/Certificate.html

Comment: Actually, `@common_name = cert.subject.to_a.select{|name, _, _| name == 'CN' }.first[1]` ;-)

Comment: @DMKE: Thanks for adding that bit (though I thought I'd leave something for the OP ;)). Also, is it really worth using this if only common name is needed? Won't a quick regex like "cert.subject.to_s.scan(/CN=(.*?)\//)[0][0]" work too ?

Comment: Sure, a `scan` would suffice. But that totally hides the possibility of a field-by-field access in the documentation. Requirements like *“I need X”* should be read as *“**for now**, I need X”*. Without (much) overengineering, a `…to_a.select…` eradicates any complex regexes in the future. :-)

Comment: True, agree with that :)

Comment: @Sam could you please update your answer, so it uses the correct `cert.subject.to_s`? When i just use `cert.subject` i get  `=> #<OpenSSL::X509::Name:0x00000002fe11e8>` and it would be also great if you could add the solution of DMKE. I improved it a little bit by using find instead of select: `cn = cert.subject.to_a.find { |name, _, _| name == 'CN' }[1]`